# Angular 2 - *ngif not refreshing when variable update from oberservable subscribe

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

in the html i have warning should only be shown when a error state occurs like thius

```
<div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="error">
    <strong>Not saved!</strong> There was an error when saving the project. Please try again later.
</div>
```

this works fine. but when I set the value from a observable the ngIf doesn't get the updated value.

Here the simplified code which always sets error to true for testing purposses

```
export class createProjectComponent {
    constructor(private service:ProjectsService){

    }

    model = new myModel();
    error = false;
    submitForm(){    
        this.service.createProject(this.model).subscribe(i=>{
            this.error=true;
          }
    }
```

is there some kind of notification i have to trigger?

Comment: What is `this.service.createProject(this.model)` doing? Are you using some non-Angular2 library there?

Comment: currently it does nothing and just returns an observable (no error occurs) . And I also debugged that the error property is set to true . I assume it has to do with some kind of background task that rxjs is creating

Comment: Can you reproduce in Plunker?

Comment: Your code looks fine. I also used *ngIf like you and it should work. You wrongly use `subscribe()`. Try `.subscribe( data => {}, error => {this.error =true});`

Comment: @Kuba he's not wrong by using .subscribe as he did. He just doesn't handle the error ;)

Comment: Please create a Plunkr. I did try to make one here : http://plnkr.co/edit/c64OLrDKJldBkoRqY8Jr?p=preview and nothing's wrong (wait 2s and you'll see the error). Think maybe to add some more relevant code.

Comment: @Maxime I know it should work. I just don't understand why he's trying to handle error in "successful" callback :P

Comment: @Kuba oh right I didn't even focus on variable name haha.

Comment: @Maxime it was just for testing things out :)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can try if this fixes your issue:

```
constructor(private cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef) {}

submitForm(){    
    this.service.createProject(this.model).subscribe(i=>{
        this.error=true;
        this.cdRef.detectChanges();
    }
}
```

If it does there is some code in `this.service.createProject(this.model)` that causes execution leaving Angulars zone.

**update**

You don't need this if you use `()=>` everywhere instead of `function ()` and if you don't pass functions just by name like `someFunc(mycallback)` but instead with `someFunc(() => mycallback())` or `someFunc(mycallback.bind(this))`

Comment: doesn't change anything

Comment: Then it's unlikely the cause can be derived from the information available in your question. Please try to reproduce in Plunker.

Comment: Have you checked `this.error=true;` is executed at all?

Comment: yes I debugged it an made a console.log. @plunker ill check it but this will be timeconsuming as I need angular 2 and all that horrible plumbing stuff...

Comment: @BoasEnkler pro-tip : Go to angular page on github : https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/new and create a new issue. They give you a link with a pre-setup plunkr to kickstart some ng2 demo. Plunkr : http://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:AvJOMERrnz94ekVua0u5

Comment: Or just use the `[ New | V ]` button in Plunker. There is a ready-to-use Angular2 TS template as well.

Comment: why do I need this here. I never need it anywhere. I mean, it works. but why do I need it?

Comment: > It turned out this worked because I was using onAuthStateChanged(), which wants to update an observer and doesn't just update a variable. Using detectChanges caused issues when routing. So For auth changes I just had to use authState.subscribe() which basically does the same thing I wanted to without observers, detectChanges, or any issues

Comment: in which situation i need to use this code this.cdRef.detectChanges(); in angular??

Comment: @HemanthSP when you change the state in a way that Angular change detection doesn't recognize it. For example when you change the state in methods invoked by change detection or in callbacks called from code that does not run inside Angulars zone.

Comment: @Günter Zöchbauer. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

Found the error. the `this` changes . in the observe `this` points to the osbervable not anymore to the component.

so I have to get a reference of the component to a variable and set error on this reference to true.

working code looks like this:

```
var component = this;

this.service.createProject(this.model).subscribe(i=>{
                component.error = true;
```

Comment: No it does not points to the subscribe as you used fat arrows ... The problem is coming from something else. It's working ok but it could be better tho ;) If you're interested in more debug post more context otherwise nevermind

Comment: You don't need this if you use `()=>` everywhere instead of `function ()` and if you don't pass functions just by name like `someFunc(mycallback)` but instead with `someFunc(() => mycallback())` or `someFunc(mycallback.bind(this))`

Comment: your right. i just wrote this as a behavior of chsarp. wasn't aware of this. many thx!